# Query a subdocuments of a subdocument/list in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say we're interested in writing an extra slow HFT engine and are using Mongo.

Here's the JSON, representing a bunch of daily forex objects:

```
{
    date: 2016-12-21,
    relation: {
        {currency: USD, value: 1.0},
        {currency: EUR, value: 0.9},
    }
},
{
    date: 2016-12-21,
    relation: {
        {currency: USD, value: 0.9},
        {currency: FJD, value: 1.0},
    }
},
```

I want to fetch all daily forex objects where:

- date = 2016-12-21
- the forex object describes the FJD currency in at least one position of it's relation list

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
db.collection.find( {
  "$or" : [
    { 
      "date" : "2016-12-21", 
      "relation.0.currency" : "JSD" 
    },
    { 
      "date" : "2016-12-21", 
      "relation.1.currency" : "JSD" 
    }
  ]
})
```

Note that the example doc wasn't valid JSON, so the query above matches all values as strings. I also assumed that "relation" was an embedded document and not an array; with "0" and "1" being string field names and not array positions.

If your "relations" were structured as an array of embedded documents like the following:

```
{
    date: "2016-12-21",
    relation: [
        { currency: "USD", value: 1.0},
        { currency: "EUR", value: 0.9},
    ]
}
```

then the query would be:

```
db.collection.find( {
  "date" : "2016-12-21",
  "relation.currency" : "JSD"
})
```

See [Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/query-documents/#array-of-embedded-documents) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem I am running into is with pymongo. It outputs a list of python dictionaries into the example given in my question (edited for clarity just now). When used with robomongo, lists were represented with [0][1] which wasn't truth. I think your second example will work.